# Build a Heartbeat alert on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

My goal is to build an Alert (and consequently, an Automation that reboots the machine) based on the fact that a VM has failed (for any reason). My VMs are long-running and run jobs.

The recommended approach seems to be to query for vms that haven't sent any Heartbeat in the past, say, 15 minutes.

Such queries are readily available in the predefined queries right on the Logs query interface.

[image]

For instance:

```
// Not reporting VMs 
// VMs that have not reported a heartbeat in the last 5 minutes. 
// To create an alert for this query, click '+ New alert rule'
Heartbeat 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(24h)
| summarize LastCall = max(TimeGenerated) by Computer, _ResourceId
| where LastCall < ago(5m)
```

Then I try to build an Alert by using the New Alert Rule button below:

[image]

The the following error message is displayed:

*The query didn't return the TimeGenerated column. Please edit the query and include the TimeGenerated column.*

[image]

How to get this to work?

What I had in mind for the Alert logic was: Less or equal than 0. Does this make sense as well?

Any other idea on how to reboot a failed VM would be welcome.

Comment: Using Automation account to configure a powershell runbook should achieve both of the objectives. Take a look at samples that are out of the box and tweak to customize to your needs. For example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management

Comment: where do you see the error? can you add a more detailed steps and some screenshots?

Comment: @IvanYang updated with screenshots

Comment: @lajarre, in the last screenshot your provided, why it's preview for "create alert rule(preview)"? At my side, it's not preview. And the UI is totally different than mine. Are you using a trial subscription?

Comment: @lajarre Can you try renaming `LastCall` to `TimeGenerated` and try again?

Answer (score 0):

The results returned by your query are used to populate the alert definition. The results of your query (if you get VMs with no heartbeats) is Computer, ResourceId and LastCall. Since the query does not yield TimeGenerated, you will not be able to configure alert based on TimeGenerated.